# SQL: Optimize the query on large table with indexing

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

For example, I have the following table:

```
table Product
------------
id
category_id 
processed
product_name
```

This table has index on columns `id` `category_id` and `processed` and `(category_id, proccessed)`. The statistic on this table is:

```
select count(*) from Product; -- 50M records
select count(*) from Product where category_id=10; -- 1M records
select count(*) from Product where processed=1; -- 30M records
```

My simplest query I want to query is: (select * is the must).

```
select * from Product 
where category_id=10 and processed=1 
order by id ASC LIMIT 100
```

The  above query without limit only has about 10,000 records.

I want to call the above query for multiple time. Every time I get out I will update field `processed` to 0. (so it will not appear on the next query). When I test on the real data, sometime the optimizer try to use `id` as the key, so it cost a lot of time.

How can I optimize the above query (In general term)

P/S: for avoiding confuse, I know that the best index should be (category, processed, id). But I cannot change the index. My question is just only related to optimize the query.

Thanks

Comment: This link is really really helpful for indexing tips: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql and Gordon's answer should give you the best performance

Comment: Try `force index (processed)`

Comment: To prevent MySQL from using an index with leading column of `id` (i.e. using the index to avoid a "Using filesort" operation), we change the ORDER BY clause to operate on an expression rather than a bare column. For example, if `id` is numeric type, we could do `ORDER BY id + 42 ASC`.  If `id` datatype a date, datetime, etc we can do `ORDER BY id + INTERVAL 42 DAY ASC`. If it's character type, we could do `ORDER BY CONCAT('42',id) ASC`

Comment: @spencer7593 thanks for that information. Can you explain for me why and are there any sources mention this. Thanks.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-optimization.html   in particular, the section on the use of indexes to satisfy ORDER BY. When an index can't be used, there's a Using filesort operation. And that can be expensive on large sets. If the optimizer is using an index with leading column of `id`, then it must be using that index to satisfy the ORDER BY... the optimizer must think it's going to be faster to examine every row in order, and determine if it satisfies the WHERE conditions, and stop after it finds 100 rows.  MySQL can't use an index to satisfy ORDER BY on expression.

Answer (score 5):

For this query:

```
select *
from Product
where category_id = 10 and processed = 1
order by id asc
limit 100;
```

The optimal index is on `product(category_id, processed, id)`.  This is a single index with a three-part key, with the keys in this order.

Comment: For the best, it should be. But this table is huge, and I cannot change the index.

Comment: @TrầnKimDự if you cannot change indexes, then how do you expect to improve performance ?

Comment: I just guess, that there is some way, for example, breaking into 2 queries, then joining back again. My apologies if my guess is not correct.

Comment: and sometimes the optimizer has wrong guess. They use `id`  as index instead. (the reason obviously because I use `select *`, but I  cannot change that)

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have `INDEX(category_id, processed)`, there is virtually no advantage in also having just `INDEX(category_id)`.  So `DROP` the latter.

That *may* have the beneficial side effect of pushing the Optimizer toward the composite `INDEX(category_id, processed)`, which is at least "better" for the query.

Without touching the indexes, you *could* use a `FORCE INDEX` mentioning the composite index's name.  But I don't recommend it.  "It may help today, but hurt tomorrow, after the data changes."

Why do you say "But I cannot change the index."?  Newer version of MySQL/MariaDB make ADD/DROP INDEX much faster than older versions.  Also, `pt-online-schema-change` is provides a fast way.